# How can users write a bio on their profile page?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I'd like my users to be able to write a bio on their profile page. Therefore, I added a long text field called 'Bio' to the user accounts. I created a view that shows the user's bio and wanted to add a link to only let the user edit his/her bio. Unfortunately, I only found a link that redirects the user to a page where he/she can edit his/her whole profile - which isn't exactly what I want.

Did I miss something?

I tried to solve this in another way. I created a content type called 'Bio' and a rule that creates a 'Bio' node with title *My bio* automatically when a user is created. Users don't have permission to add another bio, but they can edit their own 'standard' one. Now, I don't want the title field to be displayed on the edit form, because I'd like the titles to remain *My bio*.

How can I do this?

Comment: you can use `hook_form_alter` to hide `title` in second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: the second/existing option, if you have a custom module already, could do a `form_alter()` on the node form to remove the title field.  Or, you could look into the [auto_nodetitle](https://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module that does this for you:

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of
>   the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title
>   fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.
>
> When the token module is installed it's possible to use various node
>   data for the auto generated title - e.g. use the text of a CCK field
>   (since 5.x).
>
> Advanced users can also provide some PHP code, that is used for
>   automatically generating an appropriate title.

If instead you wanted to stay/go back to the first option, you could create a menu link/path like `user/%/edit/bio` that presents the `user_profile_form` that has been `form_alter()`ed to show only the bio field based upon the fact that it was called from this new path.

Comment: Which option is the most efficient according to you?

Comment: Both ways are pretty much equal efficiency wise. Easewise, the `auto_nodetitle` should do all you want pretty much "out of the box" without any/much further programming on your part.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I'm using the Automatic Nodetitles module and it does exactly what I want!